# MySQL - Remove duplicates based on same date entry

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id |        date         |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2017-01-01 12:30:00 |
|  2 | 2017-01-01 12:30:00 |
|  3 | 2017-01-02 00:00:00 |
|  4 | 2017-01-03 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

This is part of a large dataset (with various joins).

I want to remove the entries with a duplicate date while keeping one of them i.e.:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id |        date         |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2017-01-01 12:30:00 |
|  3 | 2017-01-02 00:00:00 |
|  4 | 2017-01-03 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

Does anyone know a good approach for this. I had thought sorting then iterating through each row and deleting based on whether date has been encountered before. Or using COUNT/HAVING on the date.

Thanks.

Comment: `Group by` date may help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use aggregation:

```
select min(id) as id, date
from t
group by date;
```

If you have additional columns, this won't work so well.  Instead, use a filter on the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select min(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.date = t.date);
```

Comment: I used the latter approach. Thanks Gordon

Answer (score 2):

you simple use `group by` function to get your result by

```
SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY date;
```

**but Some time `group by` not work in this situation properly [see here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160216/group-by-gives-wrong-result-with-min-aggregate-function)**

you should use

```
1)using min(id)

SELECT * FROM your_table GROUP BY date HAVING MIN(id);

2)using min(date)

SELECT * FROM your_table GROUP BY date HAVING MIN(date);
```